# Fluent UI Listbox - Disable black border on mouse down

Tags: html, css, fluent-ui

I'm using the Listbox from the Fluent UI Web Components, example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/components/listbox?pivots=typescript)

What I don't like is that when you press down the mouse, it shows a thick black border, see screenshot: [image]

How can I disable that? I've tried setting a border on the fluent-listbox, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, found the solution with this CSS:

```
fluent-listbox {
  outline: 0;
}
```